# Stop CodeIgniter Model to format SQL Date fields

Tags: codeigniter

I have an MSSQL Database table with Date field. When selecting that field with codeigniter, it returns a formatted date different from the format found in the database. What I need is for the CI model to return the original date format so I can format the date as I needed.

**TSQL returns**

```
2018-05-18
```

**Displayed as HTML**

```
May 18, 2018 12:00:00:AM
```

**I need to display as is**

```
2018-05-18
```

Comment: pls be precise, what you want to achieve

Comment: hi, @pradeep, I have updated my statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

```
$returned_date ='May 18, 2018 12:00:00:AM';

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('M d, Y H:i:s:A', $returned_date);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
 /*Output 2018-05-18*/
```

Working example : https://eval.in/1005671

For more : http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: Thank you! This helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

When you are displaying it on your html/php please use below code to format your date string:

```
$newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($originalDate));
```

Comment: This doesn't works. The $originalDate has been always formatted as 'M d, Y H:i:s:A', so, when trying to convert using that, it just returns '1970-01-01'.

Comment: Okay..that mean the date returned from db is not the date that you have posted in question. else it should work. strttotime will work if the given date is correct unix date.